# Visualizing a 3D NumPy array with PyOpenGL

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, glsl, pyopengl

I want to create a PyOpenGL/QtOpenGL widget that will allow me to visualize an arbitrary NumPy 3D matrix, not unlike the following Hinton diagram envisioned as a "cube of cubes" instead of a "square of squares":

[image]

I'm having a bit of a rough time with OpenGL though. Here is my code thus far:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtOpenGL
import numpy as np

action_keymap = {
  # 'a': lambda: glTranslate(-1, 0, 0),
  # 'd': lambda: glTranslate( 1, 0, 0),
  # 'w': lambda: glTranslate( 0, 1, 0),
  # 's': lambda: glTranslate( 0,-1, 0),

  'a': lambda: glRotate(-5, 0, 1, 0),
  'd': lambda: glRotate( 5, 0, 1, 0),
  # 'W': lambda: glRotate(-5, 1, 0, 0),
  # 'S': lambda: glRotate( 5, 1, 0, 0),
}

ARRAY = np.ones([3,3,3])

class GLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):

  def paintGL(self):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    for idx, value in np.ndenumerate(ARRAY):
      rel_pos = np.array(idx)/np.max(ARRAY.shape)
      glTranslate(* rel_pos)
      glutSolidCube(0.9/np.max(ARRAY.shape))
      glTranslate(*-rel_pos)

  def resizeGL(self, w, h):
    glLoadIdentity()
    glRotate(35,1,0,0)
    glRotate(45,0,1,0)

  def initializeGL(self):
    glClearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 1.0)

  def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    action = action_keymap.get(str(event.text()))
    if action:
        action()
    self.updateGL()

  def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    super().mousePressEvent(event)
    self.press_point = event.pos()

  def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
    motion = event.pos()-self.press_point
    self.press_point = event.pos()
    glRotate(motion.x(),0,1,0)
    glRotate(motion.y(),1,0,0)
    self.updateGL()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

  w = GLWidget()
  w.show()

  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My problems are as follows:

1) Lighting. I've been reading up on lighting and materials, but I cannot seem to get a simple light somewhere giving the shape some clarity. I'd like the simplest, most basic possible light to be able to distinguish the squares instead of them being all rendered as pure white on all sides. I know how to change the color, but it doesn't alleviate the problem. **What is the simplest light I can shine on this lattice to get some clarity on the subcomponents?**

2) It is slow. I'll work out the math to achieve proper positioning and resizing of squares down the line, but I was wondering if there was a way to vectorize the process (after all, it's only turning the index into a translation and the value into a cube size for every element in the array). Should I write an extension in cpp, wrap my code with ctypes, or is there a way to outsource the work to OpenGL explicitly? **What is the standard way to send a repetitive task to OpenGL from Python?**

Comment: IMO it's going to be very difficult to get a visualization like this to work well. Unlike the 2d grid of 2d squares, a 3d grid of 3d cubes will always suffer from occlusions, both in visibility and in lighting. It might be easier to come up with a way of "pushing" your 3d data into a 2d format -- for instance, by creating a Hinton diagram that also somehow indicates min/max/mean/std for each cell, or the like. Sounds like a really interesting visualization problem though, good luck with it !

Comment: Yeah, I realize that particularly with large matrices whatever is on the inside will not be visible from the outside (am I interpreting the term "occlusion" wrong?). I was planning on allowing the user to "zoom in" and make the blocks outside invisible down the line.

Right now all I want is to be able to tell at a glance how many cells are there in an arbitrary array. I would be happy with a wireframe cube with lines marking subdivisions.

Comment: I'm not an OpenGL expert, so even though I've set up lighting before in some limited cases, I wouldn't be able to explain how to do it. One suggestion : replace `glutSolidCube` with `glutWireCube` ?

Comment: glutWireCube works fine when there's only a few cubes, but when I go to 10x10x10 or higher it just looks like a super dense mesh. my best results so far involved following a `Joaqim` app I found on Google. I didn't do a very good job, though, since the top of all cubes was white and the bottom of all cubes was black, but it allowed some idea of what was what.

Answer (score 6):

This task is perfectly suited for [Instancing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing). With instancing an object can be rendered multiple times.

In this case instancing is used to render a cube for ach element of a 3d [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) array.

Lets assume we've the following 3D array (`array3d`) of random values in the range [0, 1]:

```py
shape = [5, 4, 6]
number_of = shape[0] * shape[1] * shape[2]  
array3d = np.array(np.random.rand(number_of), dtype=np.float32).reshape(shape)
```

For each element of the array an instance of a mesh (cube) has to be rendered:

e.g.

```py
number_of = array3d.shape[0] * array3d.shape[1] * array3d.shape[2]  
glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, self.__no_indices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None, number_of)
```

The array can be loaded to a 3D texture ([`glTexImage3D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage3D.xhtml)):

```py
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1)
tex3DObj = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, tex3DObj)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0)
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_R16F, *array3d.shape, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, array3d)
```

In the vertex shader for a single cube, a instance transformation matrix can be computes by the dimension of the 3D texture (which is equal the shape of the 3D array) and the [`gl_InstanceID`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_InstanceID.xhtml) of the element cube.
The element cube is further scaled by the value of the element in the 3D texture.

Assuming a vertex shader with a §D texture sampler uniform `u_array3D` and a vertex coordinate attribute `a_pos`:

```c
in vec3 a_pos;
uniform sampler3D u_array3D;
```

The dimension of the texture can be get by [`textureSize`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/textureSize.xhtml):

```c
ivec3 dim = textureSize(u_array3D, 0);
```

With the dimension and the [`gl_InstanceID`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_InstanceID.xhtml), the index of the element can be computed:

```c
ivec3 inx = ivec3(0);
inx.z = gl_InstanceID / (dim.x * dim.y);
inx.y = (gl_InstanceID - inx.z * dim.x * dim.y) / dim.x;
inx.x = gl_InstanceID - inx.z * dim.x * dim.y - inx.y * dim.x;
```

and the value of the element can be fetched ([`texelFetch`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetch.xhtml)):

```c
float value = texelFetch(u_array3D, inx, 0).x;
```

Finally a instance transformation matrix dependent on the element index and element value can be calculated:

```c
vec3 scale = 1.0 / vec3(dim);
scale = vec3(min(scale.x, min(scale.y, scale.z)));
vec3 trans = 2 * scale * (vec3(inx) - vec3(dim-1) / 2.0);
mat4 instanceMat = mat4(
    vec4(scale.x * cube_scale, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    vec4(0.0, scale.y * cube_scale, 0.0, 0.0),
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, scale.z * cube_scale, 0.0),
    vec4(trans, 1.0)
);

vec4 instance_pos = instanceMat * vec4(a_pos, 1.0);
```

The value can be additionally visualized by the color of the cube. For this the floating point value in the range [0.0, 1.0] is transformed to a RGB color in the [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV) color range:

[image]

```c
vec3 HUEtoRGB(in float H)
{
    float R = abs(H * 6.0 - 3.0) - 1.0;
    float G = 2.0 - abs(H * 6.0 - 2.0);
    float B = 2.0 - abs(H * 6.0 - 4.0);
    return clamp( vec3(R,G,B), 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

```c
vec3 color = HUEtoRGB(0.66 * (1-0 - value));
```

---

See also [**OpenGL - Python examples**](https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/blob/master/readme/content_python.md)

Pure [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) / [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) example program. The values of the array are changed randomly:

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *

class MyWindow:

    __glsl_vert = """
        #version 450 core

        layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_pos;
        layout (location = 1) in vec3 a_nv;
        layout (location = 2) in vec4 a_col;

        out vec3 v_pos;
        out vec3 v_nv;
        out vec4 v_color;

        layout (binding = 1) uniform sampler3D u_array3D;

        uniform mat4 u_proj; 
        uniform mat4 u_view; 
        uniform mat4 u_model; 

        vec3 HUEtoRGB(in float H)
        {
            float R = abs(H * 6.0 - 3.0) - 1.0;
            float G = 2.0 - abs(H * 6.0 - 2.0);
            float B = 2.0 - abs(H * 6.0 - 4.0);
            return clamp( vec3(R,G,B), 0.0, 1.0 );
        }

        void main()
        {
            ivec3 dim = textureSize(u_array3D, 0);

            vec3 scale = 1.0 / vec3(dim);
            scale = vec3(min(scale.x, min(scale.y, scale.z)));
            
            ivec3 inx = ivec3(0);
            inx.z = gl_InstanceID / (dim.x * dim.y);
            inx.y = (gl_InstanceID - inx.z * dim.x * dim.y) / dim.x;
            inx.x = gl_InstanceID - inx.z * dim.x * dim.y - inx.y * dim.x;
            float value = texelFetch(u_array3D, inx, 0).x;

            vec3 trans = 2 * scale * (vec3(inx) - vec3(dim-1) / 2.0);
            mat4 instanceMat = mat4(
                vec4(scale.x * value, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                vec4(0.0, scale.y * value, 0.0, 0.0),
                vec4(0.0, 0.0, scale.z * value, 0.0),
                vec4(trans, 1.0)
            );

            mat4 model_view = u_view * u_model * instanceMat;
            mat3 normal     = transpose(inverse(mat3(model_view)));
            
            vec4 view_pos   = model_view * vec4(a_pos.xyz, 1.0);

            v_pos       = view_pos.xyz;
            v_nv        = normal * a_nv;  
            v_color     = vec4(HUEtoRGB(0.66 * (1-0 - value)), 1.0);
            gl_Position = u_proj * view_pos;
        }
    """

    __glsl_frag = """
        #version 450 core
        
        out vec4 frag_color;
        in  vec3 v_pos;
        in  vec3 v_nv;
        in  vec4 v_color;

        void main()
        {
            vec3  N    = normalize(v_nv);
            vec3  V    = -normalize(v_pos);
            float ka   = 0.1;
            float kd   = max(0.0, dot(N, V)) * 0.9;
            frag_color = vec4(v_color.rgb * (ka + kd), v_color.a);
        }
    """

    def __init__(self, w, h):
        
        self.__caption = 'OpenGL Window'
        self.__vp_valid = False
        self.__vp_size = [w, h]

        glutInit()
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
        glutInitWindowSize(self.__vp_size[0], self.__vp_size[1])
        self.__glut_wnd = glutCreateWindow(self.__caption)

        self.__program = compileProgram( 
            compileShader( self.__glsl_vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER ),
            compileShader( self.__glsl_frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER ),
        )
        self.___attrib = { a : glGetAttribLocation (self.__program, a) for a in ['a_pos', 'a_nv', 'a_col'] }
        print(self.___attrib)
        self.___uniform = { u : glGetUniformLocation (self.__program, u) for u in ['u_model', 'u_view', 'u_proj'] }
        print(self.___uniform)

        v = [[-1,-1,1], [1,-1,1], [1,1,1], [-1,1,1], [-1,-1,-1], [1,-1,-1], [1,1,-1], [-1,1,-1]]
        c = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.5, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
        n = [[0,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,0,-1], [-1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,-1,0]]
        e = [[0,1,2,3], [1,5,6,2], [5,4,7,6], [4,0,3,7], [3,2,6,7], [1,0,4,5]]
        index_array = [si*4+[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3][vi] for si in range(6) for vi in range(6)]
        attr_array = []
        for si in range(len(e)):
            for vi in e[si]:
                attr_array += [*v[vi], *n[si], *c[si], 1]
        
        self.__no_vert = len(attr_array) // 10
        self.__no_indices = len(index_array)
        vertex_attributes = np.array(attr_array, dtype=np.float32)
        indices = np.array(index_array, dtype=np.uint32)
        
        self.__vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        self.__vbo, self.__ibo = glGenBuffers(2)
        
        glBindVertexArray(self.__vao)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.__ibo)
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.__vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_attributes, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        float_size = vertex_attributes.itemsize  
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 10*float_size, None)
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 10*float_size, c_void_p(3*float_size))
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, False, 10*float_size, c_void_p(6*float_size))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glUseProgram(self.__program)

        shape = [5, 4, 6]
        number_of = shape[0] * shape[1] * shape[2]  
        self.array3d = np.array(np.random.rand(number_of), dtype=np.float32).reshape(shape)

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1)
        self.tex3DObj = glGenTextures(1)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, self.tex3DObj)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0)
        glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_R16F, *self.array3d.shape, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, self.array3d)

        glutReshapeFunc(self.__reshape)
        glutDisplayFunc(self.__mainloop)

    def run(self):
        self.__starttime = 0
        self.__starttime = self.elapsed_ms()
        glutMainLoop()

    def elapsed_ms(self):
    return glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) - self.__starttime

    def __reshape(self, w, h):
        self.__vp_valid = False

    def __mainloop(self):

        number_of = self.array3d.shape[0] * self.array3d.shape[1] * self.array3d.shape[2]  
        rand = (np.random.rand(number_of) - 0.5) * 0.05
        self.array3d = np.clip(np.add(self.array3d, rand.reshape(self.array3d.shape)), 0, 1)
        glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 0, *self.array3d.shape, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, self.array3d)

        if not self.__vp_valid:
            self.__vp_size = [glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT)]
            self.__vp_valid = True
            glViewport(0, 0, self.__vp_size[0], self.__vp_size[1])

        aspect, ta, near, far = self.__vp_size[0]/self.__vp_size[1], np.tan(np.radians(90.0) / 2), 0.1, 10
        proj = np.array(((1/ta/aspect, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1/ta, 0, 0), (0, 0, -(far+near)/(far-near), -1), (0, 0, -2*far*near/(far-near), 0)), np.float32)
        
        view = np.array(((1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, -1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, -2, 1)), np.float32)
        c, s = (f(np.radians(30.0)) for f in [np.cos, np.sin])
        viewRotX = np.array(((1, 0, 0, 0), (0, c, s, 0), (0, -s, c, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)), np.float32)
        view = np.matmul(viewRotX, view)
        
        c1, s1, c2, s2, c3, s3 = (f(self.elapsed_ms() * np.pi * 2 / tf) for tf in [5000.0, 7333.0, 10000.0] for f in [np.cos, np.sin])
        rotMatZ = np.array(((c3, s3, 0, 0), (-s3, c3, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)), np.float32)
        model = rotMatZ
    
        glUniformMatrix4fv(self.___uniform['u_proj'], 1, GL_FALSE, proj )
        glUniformMatrix4fv(self.___uniform['u_view'], 1, GL_FALSE, view )
        glUniformMatrix4fv(self.___uniform['u_model'], 1, GL_FALSE, model )

        glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        
        glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, self.__no_indices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None, number_of)

        glutSwapBuffers()
        glutPostRedisplay()

window = MyWindow(800, 600)
window.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

This won't directly create the sort of visualization you're looking for, but I would highly recommend taking a look at the `glumpy` package by Nicholas Rougier : https://code.google.com/p/glumpy/. OpenGL can be a pain to use, especially for someone who is not a graphics expert, and `glumpy` abstracts away most of the pain to let you just display `numpy` arrays on the screen.

Comment: this looks very interesting. the line *The dtype of array must be one of numpy.uint8 or numpy.float32 (because on existing restriction on OpenGL textures data types) and the shape of the array must be one of M, MxN or MxNx[1,2,3,4].* worries me a bit, however, since I want to work with MxNxK arrays. Then again, he does have a cool-looking cube in the landing page, so maybe it will work.

I will look into it.

Comment: Yeah. Even though we can see in 3D, we really only consume visualizations effectively in 2D. One way or another you're going to need to map your data onto some sort of 2D surface -- after all, eventually it's going to be displayed on a 2D screen ! One specific thought here would be to set up a `glumpy.Image` to show your 3D array, but only show one 2D slice of it at a time. Then you could attach a scroll-wheel or keyboard event to let the user change which slice is shown. In my experience something like this would be pretty fast, but it would show up as a colormap rather than cubes.

Comment: thanks for helping me out. I'll shoot you a message when I resolve this issue either way.